# error: ‘NSString’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am getting this error when i try to compile Object-c program in cygwin Windows 7, but this program executed in Xcode.

main.m:5:3: error: ‘NSString’ undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 

  {
        NSString *str1 = @"1st string";
        NSString *str2 = @"2nd string";         
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");    
    return 0;
}
```

Executed using the following CMD in cygwin,

```
gcc -c -Wno-import main.m
```

can you one help me how solve this compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows doesn't come with a Foundation library, so `NSString` isn't available by default. You should try [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/) or you could cross-compile from Xcode on a Mac using [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/). Whichever you choose, look at its documentation to find out how to use it (at a minimum you'll need to `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` and link the Foundation library).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are have the following code at the top of your .h or .m file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

You can also put the code in your Prefix.pch file.